# Tuples in Relation to Infinite Loops

Tags: python, set, tuples

I was suggested to utilize a tuple in order to create a method to keep track of my rounds, but I am confused in how I would execute such a thing. I would like to keep track of the Player's object and Computer's object and who had won each round, but with the design of my program, I am unable to understand how I could accomplish that without having to repeat the while loop 10 times and keeping track of a winner this way

```
import random
Rounds = []
Player_Score = 0
Computer_Score = 0
while Player_Score < 5 and Computer_Score < 5:
    Player_object = input("Would you like to choose R, P, or S?")
    Computer_object = random.sample("RPS", 1)[0]
    if Player_object == "R" or Player_object == "r":
        if Computer_object == "R":
             print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
        elif Computer_object == "P":
            Computer_Score += 1 
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ". You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")
        else:
            Player_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")


    if Player_object == "P" or Player_object == "p":
        if str(Computer_object) == "R":
            Player_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")
        elif str(Computer_object) == "P":
           print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ". You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
        else:
            Computer_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")


    if Player_object == "S" or Player_object == "s":
        if str(Computer_object) == "R":
             print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")
        elif str(Computer_object) == "P":
            Computer_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ". You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")
        else:
            Player_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
if Computer_Score == 5 and Player_Score != 5:
    print("The Computer has won!")
if Player_Score == 5 and Computer_Score != 5:
    print("You have won and beaten the computer")
Rounds = Rounds.append((Player_object_set, Computer_object_set))
R = "Rock"
r = "Rock"
P = "Paper"
p = "Paper"
S = "Scissors"
s = "Scissors"
print(Rounds[0][0])
```

Comment: This question has no question..

Comment: @Joe, can you be more specific please ?

Comment: What I am basically asking is how to use a tuple to print many variables at the end of a loop. I want to print. "Round X, player chose Y and computer chose Z" for how many rounds the program lasted for

Answer (score 0):

The tuples are immutable, which means that you can't add new elements inside existing tuples , but you can do that with lists. That's why you can use the list Rounds you already prepared (and I don't know what was it supposed to do) and save the objects there. At the end of the loop you can iterate over that list to extract them. If this is not what you were asking for, please be more specific. This code could be further optimised but I'm not sure whether you have enough knowledge of Python and programming in general to understand the final code - it might be overkill.

I hope this code is what you were looking for. Beware, you might still want to tell user the result at the runtime so he knows what's happening. Also, you might want to check input in order to handle letters or strings that are not desired (e.g. Q or any letter that isn't p, r or s).

```
import random
Rounds = []
Player_Score = 0
Computer_Score = 0

#Tuples to contain possible outcomes
COMPUTER_WON = ("SR", "RP", "PS")
PLAYER_WON = ("RS", "PR", "SP")

while Player_Score < 5 and Computer_Score < 5:
    objects = input("Would you like to choose R, P, or S?").upper() + str(random.sample("RPS", 1)[0]) #Upper converts input to uppercase
#objects could be tuple instead of string if you changed "+" in the line above with ",", but tuple with two strings of fixed sizes (1) wouldn't make sense
#In that case, you should change COMPUTER_WON and PLAYER_WON to look like this (("S","R"), ("R","P"), ("P","S"))
    Rounds.append(objects)
    if objects in COMPUTER_WON: #if this string "objects" exists in tuple "COMPUTER_WON" i.e. if that element is one of the outcomes where computer wins:
        Computer_Score += 1
    elif objects in PLAYER_WON:
        Player_Score += 1

if Computer_Score == 5 and Player_Score != 5:
    print("The Computer has won!")
if Player_Score == 5 and Computer_Score != 5:
    print("You have won and beaten the computer")
for i in Rounds: #For each element in list "Rounds" do the following:
    if i in COMPUTER_WON: #if that element is one of the outcomes where computer wins:
        print("You have chosen " + i[0] + " and the Computer chose " + i[1]+ ". You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")
    elif i in PLAYER_WON:
        print("You have chosen " + i[0] + " and the Computer chose " + i[1]+ ". You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")
    else:
        print("You have chosen " + i[0] + " and the Computer chose " + i[1]+ ". You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
```